# XE_SERVICES_RWLOCK in top waits

Tags: sql-server-2016, identity, sequence, waits

We start facing some uncommon waits after the last release. `XE_SERVICES_RWLOCK` waits starts to appear in our top waits. Investigation shows that this waits happen during insert to our main OLTP tables. The only thing we change in this part is that we change the insert into identity column by inserting with sequence. Actually we have not removed identity option from the column. Rather we are just doing

```
SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON

INSERT STATEMENT HERE

SET IDENTITY INSERT OFF
```

The reason that we have not removed the identity property was that it requires to rebuild the table, but our table is huge and it will require hours of downtime. The question is what are `XE_SERVICES_RWLOCK`  waits, can they appear in case of massive `SET IDENTITY_INSERT ON|OFF` statements or can the root case be using `sequence` instead of `identity`?

We run `sp_WhoIsActive` every 30 sec and save result into tables to be able to investigate problems later. You can see results from that table attached.

[image]

We are using SQL Server 2016 SP2.

Comment: Rebuild table means, that you need to create new table with same structure but without identity, insert all the data into your new table, drop existing table and rename newly created table. Also you must consider that you can have foreign key which must also be re-created.

Comment: Can you share what active Extended Events sessions are running in your environment? I would focus on those that are frequent or collect too much data via actions.

Comment: @Zikato I disable ALL my Extended Events but this waits still appear.

Answer (score 5):

### waits

Since this wait has `XE` in the name, it's presumably attached to Extended Events. It may be completely ignorable, but it's hard to tell from what you've described here. I doubt it's related to the code change you've posted.

I'd check to see if there are:

- Any Extended Events running that are collecting data aggressively
- Any queries actually waiting on it during execution

I've confirmed that the wait you're hitting is tied to XE buffering data in and out. If you've disabled all of your [active XE sessions](https://gist.github.com/erikdarlingdata/5e004b71958efff386bf645d9be16ade) and you're still hitting this wait, you need a support case with Microsoft. They should only fire when one is active, and they definitely shouldn't be hampering query performance like this.